# Fade between pics and text description color fade

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wrote this portion of code to fade between two picture.
There is also a little description below and I want that the text will change the color and also the picture fade to the second one when the mouse is "hover" the box.

Unfortunately I am having problem with the text color change and the picture fade, if the mouse is on the box the text changes the color but the pic doesn't fade to the second one.

This is what I use for the pic fade:

```
$("img.grey").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});
```

Any hint?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IronFeast/BGKFN/26/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the image change on hover of the link, not the image:

```
$(".box a").hover(
function() {
    $(this).find("img.grey").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
    $(this).find("img.grey").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BGKFN/28/

**Edit**

Or simply like: http://jsfiddle.net/BGKFN/30/

```
$(".box a").hover(function( e ) {
    $(this).find("img.grey").stop().animate({opacity: e.type=="mouseenter"?0:1}, 800);
});
```

where jQuery's `hover` is a shorthand for `mouseenter mouseleave`, 
 which means if we target the current `e` event we're getting the one of the two, and using a `ternary operator ( ? : )` we're setting opacity to `0` if true (is mouseenter) and to `1` if false (if mouseleave).

Comment: I know there was an easy solution.
AWESOME! Thank you very much

(have to wait some minutes to accept as solution)